# Какая сложность алгоритма?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, сложность

```cs
public int SearchInsert(int[] nums, int target)
{
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        if (target == nums[i])
            result = i;

        if (nums[i] < target)
        {
            if (target > nums[i])
                result = i + 1;
        } 
    }

    return result;
}
```

Как определить сложность этого алгоритма?

И как вообще определять сложность алгоритма? Всё никак не могу разобраться в этой теме.

Comment: Добавьте ваши мысли в вопрос.

Comment: Если длина массива увеличится в 5 раз, во сколько раз увеличится время выполнения  кода?

Comment: Один проход по массиву - O(n).

Comment: https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/ - отличная шпаргалка по сложностям алгоритма

Comment: Спасибо всем. Надеюсь, всё-же смогу разобраться)

Comment: Тут главное понять, сколько у вас циклов по массиву. Цикл у вас один. Вложенных циклов нет, в условиях у вас просто сравнение значений. Значит `O(n)`.

Comment: @CrazyElf а если циклов по массиву не 1, а 10 (при N = 20, например), какая будет сложность? Без вложенных циклов.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Что такое `N` у вас - длина массива или число проходов по массиву? Если число проходов, то это вообще-то цикл в цикле. А если это длина массива, то она уже учтена в `O(n)`, или, если хотите, `O(N)` - вот это `N` оно и есть. Если всё же цикл в цикле, но `N` зафиксировано, то это всё-равно `O(n)`, константы не считаются. А если это какой-то параметр, значение которого неизвестно, то можно писать `O(n*N)`, так тоже можно.

Comment: @CrazyElf т.е. если у меня массив из N элементов = 20, и я прохожусь по этим элементам циклом 1 000 000 раз (без вложенных циклов, просто один и тот же цикл вызываю 1 млн раз), то сложность все равно остается O(N)?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko А как вы вызываете этот цикл по массиву, не циклом разве? Это цикл в цикле, сложность `O(N*K)`, где N - длина массива, K - число проходов

Comment: @AndreiKhotko нужен код, иначе непонятно что ты имеешь ввиду, может быть как `O(n)` так и вообще `O(1)` - то есть, не зависит от количества элементов в массиве.

Comment: @Grundy например, "немного глупый" алгоритм поиска минимального и максимального значения в массиве. Понятно, что можно за 1 проход найти и min и max, но что если это сделать за два прохода: сначала найти min за 1-ый проход, потом за 2-ой проход найти max. В таком случае сложность алгоритма останется `O(n)` или увеличится до `O(2*n)`?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, в сложности не учитываются константы. поэтому `O(n) == O(2*n)`. В случае двух проходов - сложность все равно зависит только от длины массива линейно

Comment: А зачем это? `if (nums[i] < target) { if (target > nums[i])`? Почему две одинаковые проверки?

Comment: @Давайте_прощаться, я немного глупый, тоже увидел этот момент. Не за чем вторая такая же проверка, конечно)